# Nested routes: Assertion failed: The URL '/posts.index' did not match any routes in your application

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am playing around with Ember and I have a simple page in which I try to define some routes like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

This code is exactly copied from [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources). When I try to open `index.html#posts` in my browser, I get this error:

```
Assertion failed: The URL '/posts.index' did not match any routes in your application
```

I am running Ember 1.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also must define a posts index route

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({

});
```

or just the posts route

```
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend({

});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ENEHUQI/1/edit